# Where do i need to put my public rsa key on the server to allow passwordless ssh authentication?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have been trying to get ssh working without a password on a Linux server. I have been looking at a lot of tutorials, but I have a lack of fundamental understanding of some key concepts.

I have an old rsa public key that I generated on my client server, which I am trying to use. I log in to the Linux server, and add my public rsa key to /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys. I am still prompted for a password when attempting to log in.

My question is whether or not that is the correct authorized_keys file to add my key to. It seems odd that I would put it in my own user directory, but most explanations I have seen on setting up ssh tell me to put my public key in  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

As a follow up question, is the public key that I generated years ago on my client my identifier for all shh connections or do I need to generate a new one?

**UPDATE**
The errors that are being logged read

```
trying public key file /home/bsayegh/.ssh/authorized_keys
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/bsayegh/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The permissions on the file/directory are:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 bsayegh root     401 May 24 14:30 authorized_keys
 drwx------. 2 bsayegh root    4096 May 24 14:30 .
 drwx------. 3 bsayegh bsayegh 4096 May 25 11:38 ..
```

Comment: What does `ssh -v` show?

Comment: @Barmar: I just went through this exercise. ssh -v is useless for debugging it. sshd -Dd is more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the log files of the machine you want to look into them. Especially `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure`. Typically, you will find a message why sshd did not accept your public key authentication.

In general, you need to do the following

1. check that sshd allows public key authentication (see `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) -- I think this is default, so you at least should check that options, such as `RSAAuthentication` and `PubkeyAuthentication` are not explicitly disabled.
2. `chown -R ***(your user name)*** ~/.ssh` -- you own the folder
3. `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` -- only you should have access to the .ssh folder. sshd enforces this by not allowing access if this is not the case.
4. `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` -- same as for the folder. This is required for any private key you want to use
5. `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` -- some sshd daemons require this to add a bit more security by not letting others know which keys they need to steal
6. `restorecon -R ~/.ssh` -- when your system has SELINUX activated in order to set the attributes to make the files accessible to the sshd daemon; check with ls -Z ~/.ssh to see some ssh-related attributes on the files, e.g., ssh_home_t  on RedHat systems

**edit** (2016-06-07) -- add some more rules

Comment: `authorized_keys` doesn't need to be unreadable by others. It contains public keys, those are by definition "public".

Comment: I have mode `644` on my `authorized_keys` and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Barmar ... you could think like that ... but it is not the case in general.

Comment: Checked the Secure log and I see the error  "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/bsayegh/.ssh". That seems to point to what you are suggesting. Who should be the owner of the file? Currently it appears to be root. Ill set the permissions to 600. Thanks!

Comment: @bsayegh That's complaining about the **directory** permissions, not the `authorized_keys` file. Use `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`.

Comment: The owner of the file is the user himself. Just others should not see which keys are allowed to access that account. A small additional level of security.

Comment: set permissions to 700 and get  "trying public key file /home/bsayegh/.ssh/authorized_keys" 
"Could not open authorized keys '/home/bsayegh/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied". I cant personally browse the directory anymore either, so im guessing I am not the owner?

Comment: For a fedora and a centos system, the .ssh directory and .ssh/authorized_keys file should be owned by the user himself. The permissions should be 700 and 600. Not sure how this is for older sshd versions and other OSes

Comment: So it turned out to be a litany of issues. I set .ssh permissions to 700, authorized_keys to 600, and made myself the owner of each. I also had some other problems that I was able to figure out by digging through the logs. Thanks!